# Put primary keys in cassandra for updating record

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a table in cassandra.
My task is:
I want to select records with time range (so timestamp must be primary key, and not use allow filtering)
when I insert record and provider_id and filename exists in table, the record is updated

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    name text,
    filename text,
    timestamp timestamp,
    is_deleted boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY (provider_id, filename, timestamp)
)
```

Comment: Do you want to select or update?

Answer (score 3):

**You can't update primary key column, It will insert another record**.
That's how cassandra work.
You have to select the timestamp with provider_id, filename then delete with provider_id, filename and timestamp  and reinsert with new timestamp

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select items depending on a timerange you should use clustering columns. Your create statement should be:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    provider_id UUID,
    name text,
    filename text,
    timestamp timestamp,
    is_deleted boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY ((provider_id, filename), timestamp)
)
```

Now provider_id + filename is your partition key, and timestamp your clustering column.

> The composite partition key consists of `provider_id` and `filename`. The
>   clustering column, `timestamp`, determine the clustering order of the
>   data. Generally, Cassandra will store columns having the same
>   `provider_id` but a different `filename` on different nodes, and columns
>   having the same `provider_id` and `filename` on the same node.

This means that you can now query your data like this:

```
SELECT * FROM test 
WHERE provider_id = 1
AND filename = "test.txt"
AND timestamp >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00+0200' AND  ts <= '2016-08-13 23:59:00+0200'
```

And for a possible update:

```
UPDATE test 
SET name = "test-new"
WHERE provider_id = 1
AND filename = "test.txt"
AND timestamp >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00+0200' AND  ts <= '2016-08-13 23:59:00+0200'
```

More [info](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/cqlCommandsTOC.html)