# Cassandra - Is it OK to update a table's column which is aslo used for materialized view's PK?

Tags: indexing, cassandra, updates, data-modeling, cassandra-3.0

I wonder if its OK to change a table's value, which is also used in a materialized view's PK?
If its OK, I will appreciate if someone can explain on how it works (insert and delete?)

For example, Having the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id uuid,
    username text,
    category int,
    created timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (username) //Show users ASC
)

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW category_username AS
    SELECT username, category
    FROM keyspace.users
    WHERE username IS NOT NULL AND category IS NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (category, username); //Show users by category ASC
```

Then I change the user's category to something different then what he have at the moment:

```
UPDATE keyspace.users
    SET category = 'SomeUniqueInt'
    WHERE username = 'IAmGroot' IF EXISTS;
```

Will the category_username be updated accordingly?

It's an evaluation of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922020/put-primary-keys-in-cassandra-for-updating-record).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Similar to Normal table Cassandra will delete the previous record and insert the updated category with username from the materialized view.**

In Cassandra delete create tombstone

1. Tombstone take up space and can substantially increase the amount of storage you require.
2. Querying tables with a large number of tombstones causes performance problems and it causes Latency and heap pressure.

So if you frequently update user category, then huge tombstone will be generated.